# Maintain breakpoints after closing Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

In the VBEditor, you can add breakpoints in the code that will stop the macro running, and allow you to step in to the code.

However, after closing Excel, these go away and are not remembered.

Is there a way to save the breakpoints in the code between sessions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can insert a

```
Stop
```

Line in the code, which will effectively do the same as a breakpoint.

However, this requires you to edit the code and you'd have to go in later and remove all such lines instead of just undoing a breakpoint (or removing all breakpoints with <kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+F9</kbd>).

Comment: `Debug.Assert False` provides similar functionality.

Comment: @Jeeped - Thanks for that!  I'll look in to this further, but I guess for just stopping the code, there's no real difference in `Stop` and `Debug.Assert False`?  (I've seen `Debug.Assert` in passing before, but never really looked in to it.)

Comment: No real difference if you're using False for the argument but you can substitute a logical condition that only breaks the code execution if resolved as False. Consider `For i = 1 to 10 \n If <some condition> then Exit For \n Next i`. If you put `debug.assert i <= 10` after the `Next i` then it only breaks if you have iterated through the entire loop.